# Можно ли портировать Flash приложение на Android

Tags: android, flash

Здравствуйте! Есть несложная флеш игра, с Action script, можно ли портировать ее на Android. Или как-то переработать с минимальными затратами по времени. Слышал что-то про Adobe AIR но не работал, может ли мне это помочь, или есть какие-то другие варианты?

Comment: AIR может помочь. Но просто нажатием двух кнопок портировать не получится

Answer (score 1):

Adobe AIR поможет. Но не все так просто. Между web flash и mobile adobe air большая разница. Надо понимать, что делаешь и знать ограничения устройства.